# My event handler won't get triggered

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to server side bind an event handler to my grid i created via server side aswell. But the eventhandler don't seem to get triggered. I have put a breakpoint inside the `RadGrid_Equipment_ExcelExportCellFormatting` event/method but the program won't get inside the event/method. Have I missed something?

```
public void blabla()
{     
    using (RadGrid dg = new RadGrid())
    {
        dg.DataSource = dt;

        dg.ExportSettings.IgnorePaging = true;
        dg.ExportSettings.OpenInNewWindow = true;
        dg.ExportSettings.Excel.Format = GridExcelExportFormat.Xlsx;
        dg.ExportSettings.Excel.DefaultCellAlignment = HorizontalAlign.Center;
        dg.ExportSettings.ExportOnlyData = true;            
        dg.DataBind();
        Page.Controls.Add(dg);
        dg.ExcelExportCellFormatting += new OnExcelExportCellFormattingEventHandler(RadGrid_Equipment_ExcelExportCellFormattin);
        dg.MasterTableView.ExportToExcel();
    }
}

private void RadGrid_Equipment_ExcelExportCellFormattin(object sender, ExcelExportCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: Currently however the example shows it as empty - perhaps the compiler is ditching it because theres nothing to do

Comment: Why the `RadGrid` is initialized in using block?

Comment: i been told to do so. dont know why. does it matter?

Comment: @BugFinder i have tried put som code insde the event but still the same problem

Comment: sadly I dont have radgrid but https://www.telerik.com/forums/exportcellformatting-event-not-getting-fired shows that in 2014 they were saying that the formatting was obsolete and to use other options.. you did google right?

Comment: yeah i saw that link